# How to point my program to the values I input into the list? C++

Tags: c++, list, function, shapes

So I am a beginner and I am trying to figure out this problem:

This is my piece of code:

```
int main()
{

  list<Shape*> shapes;
  shapes.push_back(new Pentagon(Vertex(20, 10), 8));
  shapes.push_back(new Rhombus(Vertex(50, 10), 8));

  list<Shape*>::iterator itr = shapes.begin();
  while (itr != shapes.end())
  {
    (*itr)->drawShape();    

    c.gotoXY(20, 10);
    cout << (*itr)->area();
    // scale shape (double it)
    // draw shape
    // rotate shape by 20 degrees
    // draw shape

    itr++;
  }

  cout << endl << endl << endl << endl << endl << endl << endl << endl;
  system("pause");

}
```

So basically, first block of text is adding two new objects, Pentagon and Rhombus to the list shapes.

These objects have 3 values, x and y coordinates and the size.

and then in the iterator I am trying to draw these shapes in a console which is working just fine, but I have a problem with the `c.gotoXY();` function. 
Basically, I want the area to be displayed in the middle of the shape. It works just fine when I type in the coordinates manually: `(20, 10)` in the code, for Pentagon. You can see that it is exactly the same as values I input when I add new stuff to the list.

But I am going to have a lot of different shapes and I can't just manually type in values.

I would like to link the values of x and y to the values of the objects in my shapes list like this:

http://puu.sh/hlMMR/2f536907f9.png

so  basically, every time the iterator goes around it would take the x and y values of the next object on the list and stick them in the `c.gotoXY();`

I hope I explained it clearly enough because I barely understand it myself.

Please help.

@edit~~~~~~~~~

when I try to use

```
c.gotoXY(Vertex.getX(), Vertex.getY);
```

I get this:
error C3867: 'Vertex::getY': function call missing argument list; use '&Vertex::getY' to create a pointer to member

Comment: supply some sort of get methods for `Vertex` so that you can do something like `c.gotoxy(itr->getX(), itr->getY());`

Comment: My vertex.cpp and vertex.h have getX()l and getY(); functions that return these values but I dont know how to incorporate them into the c.gotoXY(x, y) to make it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I imagine your `Shape` type has a member function something like:

```
Vertex getPosition() const;
```

And your `Vertex` type has member functions something like:

```
int getX() const;
int getY() const;
```

In which case you might code something like:

```
Shape* curr=*itr; //Get a pointer to the current shape from the iterator.
Vertex pos=curr->getPosition());//Get the position of the current shape.
c.gotoXY(pos.getX(),pos.getY());//Goto the current position of the current shape.
```

In place of:

```
c.gotoXY(20, 10);
```

If you haven't yet provided ways of accessing the vertex of a shape and the coordinates of a vertex - that's the first problem to solve.

EDIT: I notice in the comments `getX()` and `getY()` are in place. It's access to the `Vertex` in the shape that's still open.

Comment: Hello thanks for your answer. My vertex.h:

`#pragma once
class Vertex
{
 int x;
 int y;
public:
 Vertex(int x = 25, int y = 25);
 int getX();
 int getY();
 void setX(int x);
 void setY(int y);
};`

We're not supposed to edit the files provided by our teacher and vertex.h is one of them.

Comment: @Macko But what about `Shape` you're not accessing the x and y of any old `Vertex`. You want to access the x & y of the vertex you specified for each shape. Your code `Vertex.getX()` is like saying "What is the x coordinate". Without saying what you want the x coordinate of.

Answer (score 1):

If the `Shape` class doesn't already have it, incorporate a `getPosition()` function that returns a `Vertex` object with the position that you initialised it with. Something like:

```
Vertex Shape::getPosition() const
{
    return m_Position;    // position of the shape (this member would have been set by
                          // the constructor when you called, for example, 
                          // shapes.push_back(new Pentagon(Vertex(20, 10), 8)); in the 
                          // main function
}
```

So in your main function, you could call it to get the position, and position the shape accordingly:

```
while (itr != shapes.end())
{
    (*itr)->drawShape();  

    Vertex position = (*itr)->getVertex();
    c.gotoxy(position.getX(), position.getY());

    cout << (*itr)->area();
    ++itr;
}
```

Also, in your edit of the original post:

```
c.gotoXY(Vertex.getX(), Vertex.getY);
```

you missed "()", so it would be:

```
c.gotoXY(Vertex.getX(), Vertex.getY());
```

However, that wouldn't work, as you're calling the member functions `getX()` and `getY()` through the class type instead of through an object. You would need to declare and initialise an object of a class before calling it's member functions, like I do with the object `position` in the while loop above.